# how to implement fling in android listview

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I would like to implement `onfling` (or some similar swipe) in listview in each and every item in list. If I swipe that particular item it should display three buttons next to the name.

Is there any idea to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented this with the help of gesture detection:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector());
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
mList.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EfficientAdapter` rather than listview. Using which you can set the`onFling` event and override it to your needs

Comment: can you please specify what is that efficientAdapter. is there any good tutorial for that? i want the same functionality of listview

Comment: Use this link for EfficientAdapter example you can used it the way you can http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: Also use this  List1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this)); for your adapter