# Gesture detector doesn't work with scrollable list activity

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I have a simple application with two views, one is a TableView and the other is ListView.  I use GestureDetector to detect the swipes across the screen similarly to how it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030389/how-to-implement-fling-in-android-listview).   Everything works OK, if the list view is populated with just a few items,  however when the ListView fills up the whole screen the gesture detection stops working.  Doing the swipe across the screen simply shows highlights one of the list items.

I think this is happening because ListView somehow steals the touch events from the GestureListener.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom listview and then implement the gesture detector inside of this i.e. on each row of the list. Could be worth a try.

Comment: I thought about it,  but looking for something cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I found that GestureDetector works fine in ListItems if you traverse a fairly accurate horizontal path. However if you stray slightly, the list scrolls and the gesture does not complete. What is going on is as follows:

- The GestureDetector starts off happily taking MotionEvents from the onTouch you install in the ListItems via setOnTouchListener().
- The ListView is meanwhile listening in on events sent to its child views via onInterceptTouchEvent()
- The ListView detects that you have started to scroll and returns true from onInterceptTouchEvent().
- From then on the MotionEvents are sent to the ListView and NOT to the original target... the ListView starts receiving MotionEvents in its onTouch handler. This continues until the final ACTION_UP. (Note that the MotionEvents from ACTION_DOWN through all the ACTION_MOVEs to ACTION_UP are considered a single gesture and everything starts again after the final ACTION_UP in the sequence)
- The original target (ListItem) gets an ACTION_CANCEL MotionEvent and the GestureDetector in your ListItem bails out. This can be seen to happen if you paste the code for GestureDetector into your app and step through it.

I needed my app to behave as if the horizontal swipe continued even if the touch strays from horizontal slightly.

SOLUTION:
This involves ViewGroup.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept) which stops the parent being able to peek at the motion events. The method involves implementing onTouchListener to detect a slight swipe (10 pixels or so) then stopping the parent intercepting motion events. The parent will then not scroll and the gesture detector continues to completion.

Here's the code:

```
private boolean mFlingInProgress = false;
private float mStartX = 0;
private final int FLING_TRIGGER_DISTANCE = 10;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    float currentX = event.getRawX();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mStartX = currentX;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (false == mFlingInProgress) {
            if (Math.abs(currentX - mStartX) > FLING_TRIGGER_DISTANCE) {
                // stop the parent intercepting motion events
                mLayout.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                mFlingInProgress = true;
            }
        } 
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mFlingInProgress = false;
        break;
    }

    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```