# view pager inside a list view row android

Tags: android, listview, swipe, android-viewpager

I could create a View Pager and add fragments to it to behave as in the Android market.
Now, I have a list view inside one of the page. Is it a good idea to add View pager to list view row. Do you think it will affect the main View Pager, or is there any other better approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

[how to implement fling in android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4030389/563306)