# Implementing Chris Banes's pull to refresh together with horizontal swipe on list view

Tags: android, listview, swipe, pull-to-refresh

I have implemented (from here- [horizontal swipe on listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174757/637755)) swipe gesture to mark-unmark items in a listview. I used Johan Nilsson's [pull to refresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) implementation to refresh items in the listview. The pull to refresh feature showed some abrupt behaviour-

- sometimes showing "Tap to Refresh"
- sometimes not hiding completely
- sometimes not changing from "Pull to refresh" to "Release..."

I have now switched to Chris Banes' [implementation](http://www.senab.co.uk/2011/11/29/new-pull-to-refresh-library/). The "pull to refresh" feature now works perfectly, but the "swipe" feature has stopped working. "Swipe" works perfectly otherwise.

```
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            new MyGestureDetector());
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        }
    };
    postListView.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

postListView is `PullToRefreshListView postListView = (PullToRefreshListView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.post_list);`

I guess it's not working because even Chris' implementation makes use of-

```
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //something over here

         }
```

Now, how do I use it at both place without any conflict? I need to detect the gestures on listview's rows as well as listen to pull in listview.

Comment: You're much better off adding an issue to the GitHub repo, please do so I can find out more information.

Comment: can you show your code..? i need help from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

postListView.getRefreshableView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener); works for me

Comment: Thanks @Ezeki, it's working for me too. I couldn't find anyway to do so, when I had posted it. It's a new change.