# Android - PullToRefresh Library used by gmail and others blocks my ListItem Swiping?

Tags: android, listviewitem, pull-to-refresh

I am using Chris Banes PullToRefresh Library in my project:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Before that I used his old library:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

In my project I also copied and pasted parts of SwipeListView library made by 47deg:
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

The problem I am facing is.. the SwipeListView (Swipe ListItem) worked great with the old PullToRegresh Library but when I had put the new library the ListItem swiping that I included in the application stopped working, I have read in here:
[Implementing Chris Banes's pull to refresh together with horizontal swipe on list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700566/implementing-chris-baness-pull-to-refresh-together-with-horizontal-swipe-on-lis)

That other people also facing the same problem, I also tried using the solution that some gave like:

```
postListView.getRefreshableView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Here's how my app implements the new PullTheRefresh (which works fine):

```
// Get View for which the user will scroll…
    mPullRefreshListView = (MySwipeList) findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh_list);

    // Create a PullToRefreshAttacher instance
    mPullToRefreshAttacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);

    // Add the Refreshable View and provide the refresh listener
    mPullToRefreshAttacher.addRefreshableView(mPullRefreshListView, this);
```

it seems like the new library blocks my OnTouch listener code of the ListViewItem of my app:
My SwipeList-

```
public class MySwipeList extends ListView   {

int frontViewId;

public MySwipeListTouchListener swipeListener;

public MySwipeList(Context context, int frontViewId) {
    super(context);

    this.frontViewId = frontViewId;

    this.swipeListener = new MySwipeListTouchListener(this);

    super.setOnTouchListener(swipeListener);
    super.setOnScrollListener(swipeListener.makeScrollListener());
}
```

}

MySwipeListTouchListener (basically this)-
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/blob/master/swipelistview/src/com/fortysevendeg/swipelistview/SwipeListViewTouchListener.java

Anyone have other suggestions on how can I fix my problem?

Comment: Hello there, i'm trying to combine the old PTR with Swipe, please see my issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776511/some-bugs-appeared-when-combining-pulltorefresh-and-swipelistview-library Hope you can help me. Thanks