# some bugs appeared when combining PullToRefresh and SwipeListView library

Tags: android, listview, swipe, pull-to-refresh

I have a list that implementing both of [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) (the old one) and [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) library.

Im following [this](https://code.google.com/p/fitup/source/browse/android/trunk/libprojects/PullToRefresh/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshSwipeListView.java?r=279) to combining those library and [this](https://code.google.com/p/fitup/source/browse/android/trunk/src/fitup/app/ui/monitor/UiUsers.java?r=279) to use it in the `Activity`.

My list can do some basic functionalities like pullUp/pullDown and swipe left/right but i encountered some bug :

1. The item position in my listview is always started from 1, i believe it should be started from 0, so i need to decrease it in my methods.
2. When i swipe an item (say, the first item), the item 5th item will be swiped to. So the index+4 item will also be swiped.

The code i used to initialize the objects :

```
private PullToRefreshSwipeListView ptrListView;
private SwipeListView resultListView;

resultListView = ptrListView.getRefreshableView();
        ptrListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener2<SwipeListView>() {

            @Override
            public void onPullDownToRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<SwipeListView> refreshView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPullUpToRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<SwipeListView> refreshView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

This is the method i used to initialize the listview :

```
private void setListview() {
        adapter = new LibraryAdapter(this, R.layout.item_library_list, new ArrayList<PurchasedItem>(), resultListView);
        adapter.setListener(new LibraryListListener() {
             //set the adapter

        });

        resultListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
            //position di -1 karena sejak gabung library swipelistview + pulltorefresh, position slalu kelebihan 1 & menyebabkan OutOfBound error.

            @Override
            public void onClickFrontView(final int position) {
                //do something here
            }

            @Override
            public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onOpened(position-1, toRight);
                lastPos = position-1;
            }

            @Override
            public void onMove(int position, float x) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onMove(position-1, x);
            }

            @Override
            public int onChangeSwipeMode(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_DEFAULT;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onStartOpen(position-1, action, right);

            }

        });

        resultListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1,
                    final int pos, long arg3) {
                //do something here

            }
        });

        ptrListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ptrListView.setLongClickable(true);
        resultListView.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(false);
    }
```

And this is my xml :

```
 <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshSwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/line_separator_repeat"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        ptr:ptrMode="pullFromEnd"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeMode="both" />
```

Please kindly help me, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you post your code here.i am getting null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same first issue like you. i think the first item (index 0) is the header.

```
int _index = index -  listView.getHeaderViewsCount();
```

I had never met your second problem. You can try this to solve touching problems :

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(listView.getRefreshableView().getTouchListener().makeScrollListener());
```

Hope this help

Comment: I dont understand where to put your second code, and i cant found listView.getRefreshableView().getTouchListener(). 

Can you kindly share your code to me? I believe i missed something small, but i cant find it.

My email : blazetamareborn@gmail.com

Thanks :D

Comment: getTouchListener() return the touchListener of SwipeListView, maybe i modified this method to public in SwipeListView.java. I put this method after the listview's initiation.

Comment: Yes, its working now. I will put my code in your answer later so people will understand better. Thanks a lot for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix problem no. 2, just add those both Override functions to your adapter:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 500;
    }
```

Comment: Seriously recommend against this solution. It defeats one of the main purposes of listview. (row recycling) Rather, simply reset the state when binding your row to your data.

Comment: Do you have a better solution?