# How to disable pulltorefresh when doing swipe to dismiss on Android

Tags: android, touch-event, pull-to-refresh, event-dispatching

I have a small issue with using the [pulltorefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) library in concert with [swipe to dismiss ListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView).
The problem is, that after the user starts swiping one item from the view out, pulltorefresh still accepts touch events and basically allow to refresh the view while swiping the item out of it, if the user swipes not only horizontally, but rather more at a diagonal.

Is there a way how to completely eats touch events in the swipe gesture? 
I understand how Android dispatches touch events. Actually the EnhancedListView returns true from onTouchEvent while swiping an item, which I guess should prevent the event to get passed to the container (with pulltorefresh).

Do you have any advices how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Seems similar (but unfortunately unanswered). Work anything out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800874/android-pulltorefresh-library-used-by-gmail-and-others-blocks-my-listitem-swip?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem too.
The answer is to disable it! ;)

```
mPullToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

and to enable it,

```
mPullToRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Tim Roes EnhancedListView

See this [issues](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView/issues/54). I was very usefull for me because they add a fonction who detect when the swipe begin and when the swipe finish.

When swipe begin, i disable the SwipeRefreshLayout and when swipe finish, i enble the swipeRefreshLayout.

Answer (score 0):

### The easiest way is

to remove listener mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(null); in **onRefresh();**
and after fetching results set it back to mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);