# Android - How can add horizontal swipe gesture in vertical scroll view like pulse app has screen view

Tags: gesture

I am newbie to android please help me, is their any possibility to add swipe action in vertical scroll view of activity screen.I am trying hard, but not getting...

Comment: Did you got the answer? I'm also facing the same problem. Please help if you have figured out

Comment: @Jaguar yeah..!!, see below answer.

Comment: Is this is specifically for `ListView`, your activity extends `ListActivity`

Comment: Yeah, In my project I have converted my vertical scroll view to List view, its working nice now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just converted vertical scroll view to Listview, Its works like a charm... Thanks to [omid nazifi and wwyt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174757/1396042), for more u can see this link [Gesture in listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921138/gesture-in-listview-android)

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    private int REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE; 
    private int REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH;
    private int REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // As paiego pointed out, it's better to use density-aware measurements. 
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = (int)(1.0f * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f + 0.5); 
        REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = (int)(250.0f * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f + 0.5);
        REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = (int)(200.0f * dm.densityDpi / 160.0f + 0.5);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            m_Starbucks));

        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); 
            }};
        lv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

        // Long-click still works in the usual way.
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String str = MessageFormat.format("Item long clicked = {0,number}", position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                String str = MessageFormat.format("Item @extra clicked = {0,number}", position);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
    }

    // Do not use LitView.setOnItemClickListener(). Instead, I override 
    // SimpleOnGestureListener.onSingleTapUp() method, and it will call to this method when
    // it detects a tap-up event.
    private void myOnItemClick(int position, View v) {
        String str = MessageFormat.format("Item clicked = {0,number}", position);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void onLTRFling() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Left-to-right fling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void onRTLFling() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Right-to-left fling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener{ 

        // Detect a single-click and call my own handler.
        @Override 
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            View lv = (View)getListView();
            int pos = ((AbsListView) lv).pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
            myOnItemClick(pos,lv);
            return false;
        }

        @Override  
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { 
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
                return false; 
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
                Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { 
                onRTLFling(); 
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && 
                Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) { 
                onLTRFling(); 
            } 
            return false; 
        } 

    } 

    private static final String[] m_Starbucks = {
        "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Caramel Macchiato", "Americano", "Mocha", "White Mocha", 
        "Mocha Valencia", "Cinnamon Spice Mocha", "Toffee Nut Latte", "Espresso",
        "Espresso Macchiato", "Espresso Con Panna"
    };

}
```