# how to trigger proper Longclick event on listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

i have to show Android Contextual action mode on long press of list view
but when we long press then some multiple event trigger and Contextual menu hide 
so is there way to handle this problems.

i also try return true on onLongClick() but its not working

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search on stackoverflow 
i found my answer  using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921138/gesture-in-listview-android)
implement GestureDetector on my listview an here is my code

set GestureDetector on listview

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); 
            }};
        mMessageListView.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

and this code of  MyGestureDetector

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener{ 

           @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onLongPress(e);
            ListView lv = mMessageListView;
            int pos = lv.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
            if (listMsg.get(pos).type==ChatItem.ITEM) {
                mMessageListView.setItemChecked(pos, !adapter.isPositionChecked(pos));
            } 
        }

       }
```

i share this ans so it can helpful for other share